# glDrawElements with per facet color

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm using `glDrawElements` to draw an index mesh:

```
voi

d init()
    {
//allocate vbo, copy actual data (m_indices,m_vertices).
//m_indices is a vector of mx3 indices of the facet.
//m_vertices is nx6 xyzrgb vertex points
     m_vBuff.create();
     m_iBuff.create();

 m_vBuff.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
 m_iBuff.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);

 m_vBuff.bind();
 m_vBuff.allocate(m_vertices.data(), int(m_vertices.size() * sizeof(VertData)));
 m_vBuff.release();

 m_iBuff.bind();
 m_iBuff.allocate(m_indices.data(), int(m_indices.size() * sizeof(uint32_t)));
 m_iBuff.release();
}
```

and the usage:

```
    ...
     m_vBuff.bind();
     m_iBuff.bind();
//define attribute which can be used in the shader
        int vp = shader->attributeLocation("a_xyz");
        shader->enableAttributeArray(vp);
        shader->setAttributeBuffer(vp, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, sizeof(VertData));


        int vc = shader->attributeLocation("a_rgb");
        shader->enableAttributeArray(vc);
        shader->setAttributeBuffer(vc, GL_FLOAT, 3 * sizeof(float), 3, sizeof(VertData));


    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_iBuff.size() / sizeof(uint32_t), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

    m_vBuff.release();
    m_iBuff.release();
```

the data in `m_vBuff` is organuzed s.t. I can have an attribute in the shader **per vertex**. How can I add color data which is **per facet**?

Comment: You can't, the attributes from a data record for each vertex. So every attribute is per vertex, there are no attributes per face (triangle primitive).

Comment: So how do I draw per triangle color? Only with unindexed array?

Comment: You have to specify the same color for each of the 3 vertices of the triangle. Note, the attributes are called **vertex**-attributes there are no face-attributes or primitive-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the data in `m_vBuff` is organuzed s.t. I can have an attribute in the shader **per vertex**. How can I add color data which is **per facet**?

There come three different strategies to mind:

1. Properly duplicate the vertex data.
2. Use of the `flat` interpolation qualifier and provoking vertex:
   If you qualify your varyings as `flat`, the data will not be interpolated across the primitive, but the data from a single vertex is used for the whole primitive. The vertex from which the data is taked is called the *provoking vertex*, and you can choose between different conventions via [`glProvokingVertex()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glProvokingVertex.xhtml).  If you have the vertices A,B,C,D and E and the triangles ABC, BCD and CDE, and forward the per-vertex color to the fragment shader as `flat`, and use for example use the `GL_FIRST_VERTEX` convention, then the first triangle will get A's color, the second triangle will use B's color and so on. This strategy will only work to a certain degree and not for arbitrary meshes, because the a single vertex could be connected to more than three triangles. This strategy still might be applied to reduce the amount of duplication which would occur in option 1.
3. Put the per-face data into some other storage and use the [`gl_PrimitiveID`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_PrimitiveID.xhtml) fragment shader input as an index into that storage. Depending on the amount of storage you need (and the GL version you're targeting), a [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), [Texture Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture) or [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) seems most appropriate.